# L2 normalization of rows in scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

As I want to use only `numpy` and `scipy` (I don't want to use `scikit-learn`), I was wondering how to perform a L2 normalization of rows in a huge scipy `csc_matrix` (2,000,000 x 500,000). The operation must consume as little memory as possible since it must fit in memory.

What I have so far is:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

tf_idf_matrix = sp.lil_matrix((n_docs, n_terms), dtype=np.float16)
# ... perform several operations and fill up the matrix

tf_idf_matrix = tf_idf_matrix / l2_norm(tf_idf_matrix)
# l2_norm() is what I want

def l2_norm(sparse_matrix):
    pass
```

Comment: Just to add: if someone else does not object to scikit-learn, it's `from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize; normalize(tf_idf_matrix)`. Shameless plug from a sklearn developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't find the answer anywhere, I will post here how I approached the problem.

```
def l2_norm(sparse_csc_matrix):
    # first, I convert the csc_matrix to csr_matrix which is done in linear time
    norm = sparse_csc_matrix.tocsr(copy=True)

    # compute the inverse of l2 norm of non-zero elements
    norm.data **= 2
    norm = norm.sum(axis=1)
    n_nzeros = np.where(norm > 0)
    norm[n_nzeros] = 1.0 / np.sqrt(norm[n_nzeros])
    norm = np.array(norm).T[0]

    # modify sparse_csc_matrix in place
    sp.sparsetools.csr_scale_rows(sparse_csc_matrix.shape[0],
                                  sparse_csc_matrix.shape[1],
                                  sparse_csc_matrix.indptr,
                                  sparse_csc_matrix.indices,
                                  sparse_csc_matrix.data, norm)
```

If anyone has a better approach, please post it.

Comment: This segfaults on my box (SciPy 0.12.0, randomly generated CSC matrix).

Comment: I'm using SciPy 0.11.0. Can you provide the code to generate the random CSC matrix?

Comment: `X = np.random.randn(10, 4); sparse_csc_matrix = csc_matrix(X)`. Newer SciPy also has a `scipy.sparse.rand` utility.

Comment: I'm getting segfaults here too. I'm not sure, but probably because `X` is not a sparse matrix. Building a sparse matrix using this code `n = 1000; density = 1e-1; ij = np.random.randint(n, size=(2, n * n * density)); data = np.random.rand(n * n * density); sparse_csc_matrix = sp.coo_matrix((data, ij), (n, n)).tocsc();` the normalization is performed correctly. I don't know the details about the core implementation of `SciPy`, but probably the sparse functions won't work if the matrix density is high.

Comment: The ordinary methods always work, in my experience, even when the matrix is actually 100% dense (that's an easy way of support sparse and dense inputs to a function). But I tend to write Cython code instead of mucking with `sparsetools`.